# How to pass data from one component to another component/parent in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to programming and started learning React a few weeks ago. I am trying to create a weather app. I created a file called Weather.js where I the fetch api data that will be displayed. One of the inputs for the api link is lat/log. I decided to create another file called Button.js, where a user will enter their lat/long and submit it. Once submitted, that lat/long will get placed on the api link (in Weather.js), to fetch that person's weather forecast.
I am able to console.log the button data in Button.js.
How do I pass that data to Weather.js?
I think I'm supposed to use props and/or a callback function, but I am at a loss on how to do it properly. Nothing has worked so far.
Thank you for your help.

```js
function Weather() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [maxTemp, setMaxTemp] = React.useState([])
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true) 
    fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=34.1030&lon=-118.4105&units=imperial&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={api}")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setMaxTemp(data.daily[0].temp.max)
    })
  }, [])

  if(loading === true){
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  } else return( 
    <div>
    High: {Math.round(maxTemp)} <br />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function Button(props) {
  
  const [lat, setLat] = React.useState([])

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(lat)
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" value={lat} onChange={e => setLat(e.target.value)} />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I see two `render` function calls, which normally you should have only one in an application. Also, I see no relationship between `Weather` and `Button` (I'm not going to question why it is named "Button" despite it is in fact a form). Are you sure this is exactly what your code looks like? If yes, then something is going really wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so first you have to import the Button into your Weather file, then you have to pass a (setState) function into that button from the parent (weather.js) and then call that inside the button with passing the data:

and you don't have to pass the Button.js into React.DOM, we do that only 1 time for the most parent component.

Weather.js:

```
import Button from './button' // pass your correct paths

function Weather() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const [maxTemp, setMaxTemp] = React.useState([])
  const [coords, setCoords] = React.useState(null)
    
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(!coords) return. // checking if no coords to skip calling API
    setLoading(true) 
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${coords.lat}&lon=${coords.long}&units=imperial&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid=${api}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setMaxTemp(data.daily[0].temp.max)
    })
  }, [coords]) // watching for coords change from button passed data

  if(loading === true){
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  } else return( 
    <div>
    High: {Math.round(maxTemp)} <br />
    <Button setCoords={setCoords} /> // here we pass the setState function into the button to get the data back once its called from inside
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Button.js:

```
function Button(props) {
  const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
  const [long, setLong] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(lat)
    event.preventDefault();
    props.setCoords({ lat, long });  // here we call the function that is passed from parent and give it the data
  }

  return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
        placeholder="Lat"
        type="number"
        value={lat}
        onChange={(e) => setLat(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Long"
        type="number"
        value={long}
        onChange={(e) => setLong(e.target.value)}
      />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two components. Simply add more state to your weather component.

You also don't need to use a form. Just create two input fields and a button.

Extract your effect code into a separate function. This way you can fire up API call on page load and on button click.

```js
function Weather() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [maxTemp, setMaxTemp] = React.useState([]);
  const [lat, setLat] = React.useState(34.103);
  const [lo, setLo] = React.useState(-118.4105);

  const apiCall = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lo}&units=imperial&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={api}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setMaxTemp(data.daily[0].temp.max);
      });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    apiCall();
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        placeholder="Latitude"
        type="range"
        step="0.5"
        max="90"
        min="-90"
        value={lat}
        onChange={(e) => setLat(e.target.value)}
      />
      <span>{lat}</span>
      <br/>
      <input
        placeholder="Longitude"
        type="range"
        step="0.5"
        max="180"
        min="-180"
        value={lo}
        onChange={(e) => setLo(e.target.value)}
      />
      <span>{lo}</span>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={apiCall}>Submit</button>
      {loading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          High: {Math.round(maxTemp)} <br />
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Weather />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```